# What is css scroll-behavior property?

Tags: html, css

I have recently noticed a `scroll-behavior` property that I can specify in my css. It can take only 2 properties: `inherit` and `initial`. I have never heard/seen it before, so I tried to look at it. The problem is that all the links are going into explaining different things about `overflow` property.

Then [I tried to test it](http://jsfiddle.net/opsxttzL/).

```
<div id="scroll">
    <div id="inside">
</div>

#scroll{
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    scroll-behavior: inherit;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#inside{
    height : 1000px;
}
```

The problem is that I see no difference. So what does it do?

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#smooth-scrolling:-the-'scroll-behavior'-property

Comment: @Quentin thanks. Strangely it is written about smooth/instant properties, but in chrome I see inherit/initial, which does nothing. It looks like it has not been implemented so far, but still appears in chrome.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#valuedef-inherit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Noticed it pop up in my Chrome Inspector as well, which lead me to this post...

#### What is the Scroll-Behavior?

Specifically referred to as CSSOM-View 'Scroll-Behavior' property, the css property was created to integrate more flexibility in CSS for DOM item scrolling. Most 'scroll-to' options that are built for websites are typically built on a JS library or plugin. Like others have mentioned, here is the release documentation - http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#scrolling

The current adopted scroll-behavior of the DOM is set to by anchor tags (example: Click Me).  When this CSS property is fully adopted in all browsers, and correctly implemented (Check out this discussion : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.platform/mrsNyaLj3Ig).  You will be able to toggle the 'instant' anchor tag scroll to more of to a 'smooth' scroll.

The real question is when we this property be available in edge browsers? Currently, it is recognized by Firefox & Chrome, but the property is not 'Active' as far as research has gone.

```css
nav{ float:left }

#scroll {
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  overflow: scroll;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#inside1 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: blue;
}

#inside2 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
}

#inside3 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#inside1">#1</a>
  <a href="#inside2">#2</a>
  <a href="#inside3">#3</a>
</nav>

<div id="scroll">
  <div id="inside1"></div>
  <div id="inside2"></div>
  <div id="inside3"></div>
</div>
```

Check out the JSFiddle to see the implementation of how the instant scroll via anchor tags currently works through the DOM - http://jsfiddle.net/timcasonjr/5t0so7n7/3/

Comment: This behaviour is now in Firefox Nightly (36) hidden behind two variables, layout.css.scroll-behavior.property-enabled & layout.css.scroll-behavior.enabled

Comment: Firefox nows ships with this property, and Google announced Chrome 39 will ship with it.

Comment: @johndrinkwater I haven't seen anyone use the property practically yet. Let me know if you see something

Comment: this is now supported with the latest Chrome stable release 61

Comment: Chrome requires the container to have overflow: auto